# Regex returns whole block instead of the result

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to extract the ip address from the stdout of the "ip addr" command. I already have the name of the active device ("wlp3s0").

I testet my regex on regex101.com and [it seems to work fine](http://regex101.com/r/gX7oX2/2).

But when executed in Python 2.7, it just returns the whole block and not the ip only.

```
IP_RE = re.compile(r"(?<=wlp3s0:)(?:.*inet\s)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})", re.DOTALL)

match = re.search(IP_RE, output_str)
if match:
    print match.group()
```

This is the output of the python script:

```
<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether a4:4e:31:56:61:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.16.58.158
```

---

My Regex:

```
/(?<=wlp3s0:)(?:.*inet\s)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/s
```

The text string:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:4e:31:56:61:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.58.158/22 brd 172.16.59.255 scope global dynamic wlp3s0
       valid_lft 85107sec preferred_lft 85107sec
    inet6 fe80::a64e:31ff:fe56:6168/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:97:0e:c4:2b:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: what is your expected output??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match.group()` [always returns the entire match if called without arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) - you need to use `match.group(1)` if you only want the contents of the first capturing group.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Don't know why I couldn't find that on my own :P

Answer (score 0):

`group(1)` will give your desire result:

```
re.search(IP_RE, output_str).group(1)
'172.16.58.158'
```